# Django : creating Queryset and add data to it

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

**Models:**

```
class MyTeam(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='match_set')
    mega_league = models.ForeignKey(MegaLeague, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name='mega_league_set')
    captain_first_team = models.ForeignKey(FirstTeamPlayer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="captain_second_team_set")
    captain_second_team = models.ForeignKey(SecondTeamPlayer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, related_name="captain_second_team_set")
    team_player_first_team = models.ManyToManyField(FirstTeamPlayer, blank=True, related_name="team_player_first_team_set")
    team_player_second_team = models.ManyToManyField(SecondTeamPlayer, blank=True, related_name="team_player_second_team_set")
```

First of all I need to add these `captain_first_team` & `captain_second_team` in one field (like add `FirstTeamPlayer` and `SecondTeamPlayer` in one field) . How?

**Views:**

```
def add_to_my_team_from_team_create(request, match_id):
    match = get_object_or_404(Match, pk=match_id)
    my_team = MyTeam.objects.create(match=match, user=request.user)
    return redirect('team_create', match.pk, my_team.pk)

def team_create(request, match_id, team_id):
    match = get_object_or_404(Match, pk=match_id)
    my_team = get_object_or_404(MyTeam, pk=team_id)
    first_team_player = match.first_team.first_team_player.all()
    second_team_player = match.second_team.second_team_player.all()

    context = {
        'match': match,
        'my_team': my_team,
        'first_team_player': first_team_player,
        'second_team_player': second_team_player,
    }
    return render(request, 'main/team_create.html', context=context)

def add_first_team_player(request, match_id, team_id, player_id):
    match = get_object_or_404(Match, pk=match_id)
    my_team = get_object_or_404(MyTeam.objects.filter(user=request.user, match=match.pk), pk=team_id)
    first_team_player = get_object_or_404(match.first_team.first_team_player, pk=player_id)
    my_team.team_player_first_team.add(first_team_player)
    return redirect('team_create', match.pk, my_team.pk)

def remove_first_team_player(request, match_id, team_id, player_id):
    match = get_object_or_404(Match, pk=match_id)
    my_team = get_object_or_404(MyTeam.objects.filter(user=request.user, match=match.pk), pk=team_id)
    first_team_player = get_object_or_404(match.first_team.first_team_player, pk=player_id)
    my_team.team_player_first_team.remove(first_team_player)
    return redirect('team_create', match.pk, my_team.pk)
```

In views, 1st I create a `MyTeam` using `add_to_my_team_from_team_create` function and then add data on the fields using `add_first_team_player` and also I can remove data from fields using `remove_first_team_player`. But I need the opposite one. That means, I need to add fields then when I press save button in template then it will save in `MyTeam`.

**team_create template:**

```
{% for first_team_player in first_team_player %}
    <tr id="wk">
       <td>
          <img src="{{ first_team_player.player_image.url }}">
          <div>
              {{ first_team_player.player_name }} <br>
              {{ match.first_team.name }}
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
           {% if first_team_player in my_team.team_player_first_team.all %}
              <a href="{% url 'remove_first_team_player' match.pk my_team.pk first_team_player.pk %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Remove -</button></a>
           {% else %}
              <a href="{% url 'add_first_team_player' match.pk my_team.pk first_team_player.pk %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Add +</button></a>
           {% endif %}
         </td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
<a href=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Save</button></a>
```

Here in template when I press `Add +` button then this player add to `MyTeam` model and when press `Remove -` button then this player remove from that model.

Now my question is all about 2 point:

1. I want to make some logic here in creating `MyTeam`. I need max 7 player from 1 team (when max player add then `Add +` button will disable) and other player from another 1 team, total player will be 11 (when total player add then `Add +` button will disable for all players). 1st, `Save` button remain disable,, when 11 player complete in `MyTeam` then it will enable and pressing these players will save to `MyTeam`. In this way one QuerySet will make.
2. If I create `MyTeam` 1st and add data on it's field,, then it can be a empty team. But here I can't make any empty team. So, 1st I need to add data on fields and then when press `Save` button it will make a new team with all data.

How can I solve this 2 problem??

**For better understanding, I want to make like this** [team create of dream11](https://www.dream11.com/cricket/create-team/1156/15819?returnUrl=%2Fcricket%2Fleagues%2Fwi-w-vs-au-w-odi%2F1156%2F15819)
. **Help me in details please after surveying given link..**

Comment: have a look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: It would probably be easier to use javascript to create the logic in your last two questions, in combination with formsets to submit all the data at once (and validate it in your formset). But your question is way too broad to be answered here, you need to first try things and ask questions when you are facing a more **specific** problem.

Comment: @Risadinha: please give some code for me to make logic about total 11 players (make max 7 from one team and another from other team)..
please make an answer of my question. help me please

Comment: @dirkgroten: Sir I need the way to start solving my problem. Please give me start by giving an answer. How can I use javascript with django? Please help me by giving some code in answer section.

Comment: @dirkgroten : How to add these `captain_first_team` & `captain_second_team` in one field (like add `FirstTeamPlayer` and `SecondTeamPlayer` in one ManyToMany field)

Comment: I don’t understand your question there are two fields (also two m2m fields) what do you mean “in one field”?

Comment: @dirkgroten: Need,, `captain = models.ForeignKey(FirstTeamPlayer and SecondTeamPlayer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)` and `team_player = models.ManyToManyField(FirstTeamPlayer and SecondTeamPlayer, blank=True)`...add 2 Model class in one field. But this process is not working. How to solve this, Sir?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense at all. But why do you even have separate FirstTeamPlayer and SecondTeamPlayer models? That makes even *less* sense.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I need 2 team but I need 1 captain from these 2 team. that's why... is it possible `captain = models.ForeignKey(FirstTeamPlayer and SecondTeamPlayer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)`?? I hope, it makes sense..

Comment: @DanielRoseman sir, Can you please give me some tips to solve my whole Question?? What will be the easiest way??

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Why would teams be separate models?

Comment: @DanielRoseman sir, I need 2 team but I need 1 captain from these 2 team. that's why... is it possible `captain = models.ForeignKey(FirstTeamPlayer and SecondTeamPlayer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)`?? I hope, it makes sense..

Comment: For the third time. **You do not need separate models for team 1 and team 2**.